# Launchpad can't find rsvg while building deb package for Precise Pangolin

Tags: 12.04, ppa, deb, launchpad

I have [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jcubic/+archive/jcubicppa) with one package: `clarity-icon-theme`. It builds fine on all versions of Ubuntu, except Precise Pangolin where it [fails](https://launchpad.net/~jcubic/+archive/jcubicppa/+build/4877560) with the following error:

```
rsvg: command not found
```

I have dependency in control file:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7), librsvg2-bin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [Contents-i386.gz](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Contents-i386.gz) file for the Precise release (warning: it's a **huge** file), it seems that `/usr/bin/rsvg` is not provided by `librsvg2-bin`.

However don't worry: in other releases `/usr/bin/rsvg` is just a symlink to `/usr/bin/rsvg-convert`, so all you have to do is change your scripts and use `rsvg-convert` instead of `rsvg`.

Comment: So if it's not in `librsvg2-bin` in what package is it then? Or is that rsvg-convert provided by `librsvg2-bin` in Precise?

Comment: `rsvg-convert` is provided by `librsvg2-bin`; no package provides `rsvg` in Precise.